# How to: Copy list control (mfc) data to clipboard?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I've created a popup menu. What should I do next and how do I retrieve element number to retrieve info?

```
void Cmfc_test123Dlg::OnNMRClickList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
    //m_Menu.CreatePopupMenu();
    POINT pt;

    POINT current_point;
    GetCursorPos(&current_point);

    HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, ID_EDIT_COPY, "&Copy\tCtrl+C");       // Copy    Ctrl+C

    // Загружаем меню из ресурсов
    //HMENU hMenu, hPopupMenu;
    //hMenu = LoadMenu(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
    //hPopupMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);

    // Отображаем меню
    TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);

    // Уничтожаем меню
    DestroyMenu(hPopupMenu);
}
```

Clist has report style and menu has only one option - "Copy". I need to copy itemdata from certain row. Thank you.

I've added this code and i'am getting messagebox when clicking copy, but nothing works when i'am pressing ctrl+c.

```
BOOL Cmfc_test123Dlg::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    int nItem = LOWORD(wParam);
    //int nItem = (int)lParam;
    if(nItem == 57634)
    {

        CString csMsg;
        csMsg.Format("%d", nItem);
        MessageBox(csMsg, NULL, MB_OK);

    }

    CWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);

}
```

I've almost solve the problem, but still there is one more thing - when i'am getting hititest info, first row is going under number 1 and last is under -1 and Listcontrol caption is 0. Why is that happening? I've used ScreenToclient() but still this issue remains. Looks like problem gone now, i don't know how it happend, but now everythig works pretty good. Thanks everyone for paying attention to my question!

Comment: What's the purpose of the menu?  Can you explain further?  What is the style of the CListCtrl?

Comment: Use `CListCtrl::HitTest` function to find an item index from `current_point`. Don't forget to translate `current_point` from screen to control coordinates.

Comment: I see, the problem is deeper. I mean how do i handle event when user pressing on the "Copy" label in popupmenu? Should i add some functions to messagemap, also the same about Ctrl+C?

Comment: Whether you use the mouse or keyboard input is of no relevance. At the time of invoking the *copy* command, you simply have to copy the **currently selected item** to the clipboard. See [Copying Information to the Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016.aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard) for details.

Comment: I don't really understand how and where to handle copy command. I've added OnEditCopy() function to my class and add this line to message map ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CListCtrl_OwnToolTipCtrl::OnEditCopy) but nothing seems to work!

Comment: The simplest way is using `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag, in this case `TrackPopupMenu` works synchronously and returns the menu item identifier of the item that the user selected, or 0, if nothing selected. So, you may handle the item selection immediately after `TrackPopupMenu` call. Otherwise, override `CWnd::OnCommand` method and handle the menu item selection there.

Comment: I've also tried Hittest() CPoint pt(GetMessagePos());
 ScreenToClient(&pt); but it always returns -1 as row.

Comment: It's probably the same mistake as before, you are using `ScreenToClient` when you should be using `List.ScreenToClient`

Comment: Yeah thanks, i change it but, as i said in update to post, something wrong with that - it returns incorrect row number, first row is returned as 1 (should be 0) and last is -1. What the hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking in the wrong window for messages. Menu message is sent to **`HWND`** parameter in the `TrackPopupMenu`. In this case it's the dialog.

Then you have `ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CListCtrl_OwnToolTipCtrl::OnEditCopy)` which is looking for messages in ListView...

```
void CMyDialog::OnContextMenu(CWnd* wnd, CPoint p) 
{
    //... 
    HWND hwnd = GetSafeHwnd(); //menu message is sent to CMyDialog 
    //HWND hwnd = List.GetSafeHwnd(); //menu message is sent to CMyListCtrl

    TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
        pt.x, pt.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
}
```

Or you can use Alex Farber's suggestion:

```
int result = TrackPopupMenu(hmenu, TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
pt.x, pt.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
DestroyMenu(hmenu);
if (result)
    TRACE("result: %d\n", result);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i've almost finished writing &CListCtrl_OwnToolTipCtrl::OnEditCopy function, but there is a problem with hit test, it returns Clist header as 0 row and last row as -1. Can't find anything about this problem.

Comment: There can be only one reason for that. `HitTest` is in `CMyDialog`, and it is using `ScreenToClient` instead of using `List.ScreenToClient`. That puts the Y-position off by about 25 pixels, so the last row is out of view.